# CSS folder with XAMPP and Craft Cms

Tags: craft3, css

I am using XAMPP with Craft CMS 3. I am doing the tutorial with craftquest. I have moved the stylesheets folder into my web folder but craft cant seem to find my folder? How do i make craft find the stylesheets folder?

Comment: Ensure that XAMPP has set the web folder to the correct location

Comment: Did you have any luck solving your problem? I can dig in more but I would like to know exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: no, not yet,   I am stuck on video 30 on the craft quest tutorial, I have set my site url to @web but apparently thats not the correct way of doing it. My project folder is within my xampp folder and craft can not read any css files or images in the .twig file

Comment: how do i ensure that xampp has set the web folder to the correct location?